# ASP.NET Identity - How to change the dbo.AspNetUsers.Id into a nonclustered index?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASPNET Identity 2.0 and need to:

- Add a new field called ApplicationUserId [int] clustered index
- Change the dbo.AspNetUsers.Id nvarchar field from clustered to a Nonclustered index

In my Models\IdentityModel.cs, I added:

```
    public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
    {
            [Index(IsClustered = true, IsUnique = true)]
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    }
```

Of course, I knew this would error since I know that Id is currently a clustered index.
How do I change the Id so that the default is not a clusered index?

Basically the reason I want to this is that our DBA does not want to use foreign keys that's a nvarchar(128) (which is this GUID from AspNetUsers table).

Or do I just create it as:

```
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
```

and then manually fix the indexes after the tables are created?

Or is my only option to use [integer keys instead of strings](http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/07/13/ASPNET-Identity-20-Extending-Identity-Models-and-Using-Integer-Keys-Instead-of-Strings.aspx)?

I'm using .NET 4.5 and installed the [Identity 2.0 Sample Project](http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/06/22/ASPNET-Identity-20-Customizing-Users-and-Roles.aspx)

```
 Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples -Pre
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: As far as I know sql server does not allow for PK to be non-clustered index, so you'll have to implement id as int or guid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work without converting the GUID [nvarchar] to an [int]

Basically I updated the Models\IdentityModel.cs file

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
```

Then I manually updated the tables (AspNetUserLogins, AspNetUserClaims, and AspNetUserRoles are referencing the AspNetUsers.Id which i still want to keep intact

```
begin tran
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserLogins_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserClaims_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId]
ALTER TABLE dbo.[AspNetUsers] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers]
--Uncomment this line in case you need to modify this table again
--ALTER TABLE dbo.[AspNetUsers] DROP CONSTRAINT [dbo.AspNetUsers_ApplicationUserId]

-- Add the constraints back, but now nonclustered
ALTER TABLE dbo.[AspNetUsers] add constraint [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] primary key     nonclustered 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

-- Add the other constraints back
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins]  WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserLogins_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserClaims_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

-- Add NEW constraint with unique clustered
ALTER TABLE dbo.[AspNetUsers] add constraint [dbo.AspNetUsers_ApplicationUserId] unique clustered 
(
[ApplicationUserId]
)
commit tran
```

When you check out the create table script for dbo.AspNetUsers, it will now look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers](
    [Id] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [ApplicationUserId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [EmailConfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [PasswordHash] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [SecurityStamp] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PhoneNumber] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PhoneNumberConfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [TwoFactorEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LockoutEndDateUtc] [datetime] NULL,
    [LockoutEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [AccessFailedCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [dbo.AspNetUsers_ApplicationUserId] UNIQUE CLUSTERED 
(
    [ApplicationUserId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```